# Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I just recently installed mySQL on my Mac running 10.10.3, but I can't create any tables or modify anything associated with my databases. When I start mysql I logs me in as '@localhost'

```
mysql> select user();
+-----------------------+
| user()                |
+-----------------------+
| username@localhost    |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| @localhost     |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE ign;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'ign'
```

I even try running this to log into my sql.

```
mysql -u username -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am so lost and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD

Comment: Space between the -u flag and username is fine, unlike -p where it should be omitted.  Are you trying to log in as root or who?

Comment: mysql  --user=fred7 --password=OpenSesame

Comment: I want to log in as root, whatever allows me to edit my databases

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: mysql -u root -p    `(will prompt for password)`

Comment: @DrewPierce when I do that I get the following, mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 3):

If you just installed it and do not know the root password, or are unsure of the password, try [resetting the root password](https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords#recover-mysql-root-password) (assuming you have admin rights on the machine). Then create a user and apply the applicable [grant permissions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Comment: root on one ain't the same as root on the other

Comment: If you're referring to root in the OS vs root in the MySQL, you are correct, but if you are root on the machine, you can stop the MySQL process and then restart it telling it to ignore the grant tables (so you don't need the MySQL root password) and then you can just set the password for MySQL root. When you're done, you can restart the MySQL process again so that it starts normally.

Comment: Step # 4: Set a new root password.how would I do that?

Comment: I've had to do this a few times. I'm happy to make it easier for someone else.